# How to detect proximity of two entities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to detect if an item is near a player. How can I do this? Also, if possible, how do you in general detect the proximity of two entities?

Answer (score 1):

You can test for items nearby a player

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ testfor @e[r=RADIUS]
```

For other commands just use the r=RADDIUS selector.

Comment: But how could I detect which player dropped the item. Sorry for not mentioning this in the question. Could I set a score (scoreboard) to the player?

Comment: Actually, I thought of a way how to accomplish what I wanted. Thanks anyway!!!